# How do I multiply vector integers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

so basically I want to multiply a vector by 60 from seconds to minutes and hours 3 times using a for loop. I also want to add 3 more values inside that vector that should store a value 60 times greater than the last integer before it.

This is what I have come up so far but it only prints out 2 times so what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector <int> seconds = { 1 };

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        i = seconds.at(i) * 60;
        seconds.push_back(i);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < seconds.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << seconds[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use your step-through  debugger. If you haven’t used it, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for loop iterates exactly once.

```
std::vector <int> seconds = { 1 };

for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    i = seconds.at(i) * 60;
    seconds.push_back(i);
}
```

`i` is set to 60, and the loop condition `i <= 3` then fails.

Use a different variable to hold this value.

```
std::vector <int> seconds = { 1 };

for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    auto x = seconds.at(i) * 60;
    seconds.push_back(x);
}
```

Or don't use a variable at all.

```
std::vector <int> seconds = { 1 };

for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    seconds.push_back( seconds.at(i) * 60 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!!!